# Enforce http to https in .net core: Api Controller Method not called

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, redirect, iis, .net-core

My .net core 2.1 application is working great. Now I want redirect http to https in production. So on IIS 8.5 I created the rules.

```
<rewrite>
     <rules>
          <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" />
               <conditions>
                   <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:5001/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
     </rules>
</rewrite>
```

One of the method is

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("user")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(string name)
{
    var result = await _database.UserTable.Where(u => u.Name == name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return Json(result);
}
```

The thing is the method is not called at all. However if I remove the rules in web.config and use the pure .net core C# code to redirect http to https such as,

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
   options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
   options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});
```

Then the method can be reached. I don't know why?

In my `Startup.cs` file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

Does it mean if we want redirect http to https, then we can't set the configuration on IIS? We **HAVE TO** do it in code?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you can use url rewrite to redirect http to https. There should be a problem with your url rule. You can use [failed requests tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to check the problem.

Comment: There is no tracing log created so I still doubt that there is a possible conflict between routing rule and .net core. Maybe Microsoft teams don't know it.

Comment: I mean you use failed request tracking to get the log, and then find out the problem based on the content in the log.

Comment: @samwu, I meant failed request tracking folder is empty. So there is no clue.

Comment: Please make sure you have enabled failed request tracking, and then test your url rule. finally, check the error message in the log.

Comment: @samwu, Of course I did it in the first place. But I am sure no log created. I still believe that when we use .net core then we can't use IIS to make rules.

Comment: Whether url rewrite in iis works has nothing to do with .net core application. you can refer to this link about the use of url rewrite with .net core application: [using url rewriting in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware)

Comment: @samwu, you may misunderstand it. My question is that you have two ways to do rewrite. One is in .net code, the other would be in IIS server to set rules. In theory either way is working. But for .net core it only works in the code to redirect. If we use IIS set redirect rules in xml, it doesn't work. If you set two ways at the same time, it also not working.

Comment: I understand what you mean, if you do rewrite in both the .net code and in iis, there will definitely be an error, but use url rewrite rule in iis, it can work for any application that can be published on iis. you can describe your requirement in detail, I can use url rewrite on iis to make a case for your reference.

Comment: @samwu, okay. Can you write a simple .net core site just say get "Hello World" strin from the server then redirect it to https? If you could do it, please remove all code for redirect from the code and make the rules on IIS. Let's see what happens. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this rule on iis:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

[image]

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show your .net core code as well? Entire Startup.cs code

Comment: I only created an empty project of .net core and published it on iis. I did not add any code, the code in Startup.cs is default.

Comment: OKAY, but would you please paste the default code? Thanks.

Comment: I have posted the code of class Startup in my answer above.

Comment: I guess that I missed `app.UseRouting();` in my code and I assume that is for redirection.